# Hiding a Dialog from users with out closing it

Tags: shell, button, swt

My application is written to run within an OOTB Application.  The users can select data from the OOTB application and store it in a WritableList in my application.  The users then can click a button in the OOTB toolbar that will open my application's base dialog.  This dialog presents the user with a table of data they have already selected.  From the base dialog they can preform different task on the data in the table.  This includes removing the data as well as selecting more data from the OOTB application.  My application will save the data until the user closes the OOTB application is closed.  But I have to give the users a button on the base dialog to remove the dialog from their view.  So the dialog is not in their way when they are working with the OOTB Application.  My base dialog is built off a TitleAreaDialog.  My first attempt was to just close the dailog in the createButtonForButtonBar method.

```
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
   Button okButton = createButton(parent, OK, "Close Aplot", true);
   okButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
      public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
         viewer = null;
         close();
      }
    });
  }
```

But the close(); was disposing all my SWT Widgets and causing a runtime error.  SWT_Widget already disposed when trying to open the dialog back up.  So with some advice, I tried to incorporating hiding the shell.  So I removed the close() and placed in getShell().

```
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
  Button okButton = createButton(parent, OK, "Close", true);
  okButton.setEnabled(true);
  okButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
     public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        viewer = null;
        getShell().setVisible(false);
    }
  });
```

}

Now I am getting a runtime Null Pointer Exception at line: getShell().setVisible(false);

If I remove the "OK" and replace it with SWT_PUSH.  It seems to work without Error.

```
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
  Button okButton = createButton(parent, SWT.PUSH, "Close Aplot", true);
  okButton.setEnabled(true);
  okButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
     public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        viewer = null;
        getShell().setVisible(false);
    }
  });
```

}

In a previous question, I was made aware that this is not good practice.

So how should I hide my dailog with out closing it?  I am assuming that I have to keep the method createButtonsForButtonBar.  So how I can I change what I have to properly take care of the shell hide?

Thanks

***EDIT***

Does this look correct?

```
 @Override
 protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(final Composite parent) {
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, "Close Aplot",
        true);
 }

 @Override
 protected void okPressed() {
   viewer = null;
   getShell().setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: you just need to hide the Dialog's Shell. I see thats what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.setMinimized(boolean)`to minimize the dialog when user clicks the button? Would that be a better solution?